# C# Get progID from COM object

Tags: c#, com, object, marshalling

i would like to know if there is a way to get the progId of a com object in c#. eg - i have a webBrowser object that exposes a document object which is COM. is there a way to figure out what the progID of that document object is?

I know you can get the object from progID, just not sure how to do the other way around.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could query for `IPersist`, and [GetClassID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688664%28VS.85%29.aspx) on it.

That gets you the `CLSID`. Then call [ProgIDFromCLSID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms690567%28VS.85%29.aspx):

[The pinvoke declaration is here.](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ole32/ProgIDFromCLSID.html)

That gets you the ProgID.

EDIT:

To query for an interface, you just do a cast in C#:

```
IPersist p = myObj as IPersist;
if (p != null)
{
    // phew, it worked...
}
```

Behind the scenes, this is what is actually happening, as shown here in C++:

```
IUnknown *pUnk = // ... get object from somewhere

IPersist *pPersist = 0;
if (SUCCEEDED(pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IPersist, (void **)&pPersist)))
{
    // phew, it worked...
}
```

(But no one bothers with writing that stuff by hand these days, as a smart pointer can pretty much simulate the C# experience.)