# c++ How to get a COM object Coclass's progid at runtime

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, atl

I need to write a function that dynamically extracts the progid from a COM object.

Is this possible?

What's the best way to do it?

EDIT: All the coclasses I need to process implement IProvideClassInfo

Comment: maybe this is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272061/how-to-find-out-a-com-prog-id

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't find my answer, it's related to c#/.NET

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there is no guarantee the information is available in first place. Even if you just instantiated an object using ProgID, you might be unale to get it back.

The easiest is to query one of `IPersist` and friends (`IPersistStream` etc.) interfaces, and call [`IPersist::GetClassID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to obtain `CLSID`. Then convert to ProgID using [`ProgIDFromCLSID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690567%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or via registry lookup.

Another option is to query `IProvideClassInfo` and `IProvideClassInfo2` to access the CLSID of interest in this alternate way.

The third option, if none of the two above worked, is to query `IDispatch` and attempt to open type library, then iterate through looking up for coclass information.

Comment: Very complete answer! All the objects I needed to process implemented IProvideClassInfo so I used this option to get the CLSID