# C# - How to test at runtime which COM coclass was used to instantiate an interface?

Tags: c#, com, interface

Suppose you have a COM interface `ICOMInterface` that is implemented by coclasses `Coclass1` and `Coclass2`. Neither of these coclasses have interfaces of their own (for simplicity's sake and to illustrate my issue).

In C#, you can create an instance of a COM interface from a coclass like so:

```
ICOMInterface myComInterface = new Coclass1();
```

Now, how can you determine whether `myComInterface` was instantiated by `Coclass1` or `Coclass2`?

Using the "is" statement like follows always returns true, and as such is useless for this purpose.

```
Debug.WriteLine(myComInterface is Coclass1) // writes "True"
Debug.WriteLine(myComInterface is Coclass2) // writes "True"
```

This would work if I was testing interfaces, not coclasses, but these coclasses do not have interfaces other than the one they both implement, `ICOMInterface`.

I am hoping that there is a simple answer to this rather generic scenario that I am overlooking, otherwise I can post more specific details if required.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the COM object implements the [IPersist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688695%28VS.85%29.aspx) interface, you can get its CLSID through the `IPersist::GetClassID()` method. This may be all you need to know what class you're working with. You can also get the human-readable ProgID through the WinAPI `ProgIDFromCLSID()` method.

See here: [C# Get progID from COM object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253368/c-get-progid-from-com-object)