# How to get LINQPad to Dump() System.__ComObject references?

Tags: c#, com, com-interop, linqpad, rcw

I am playing around with using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to rapidly develop small [ArcObjects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArcObjects) (a COM-based library for [ESRI's ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis) software) applications and have had some success in using it to `Dump()` the properties of COM objects that I initialize from .NET, but any COM objects that are obtained from an existing COM object are simply dumped as `System.__ComObject` references, which is not particularly useful:

[image: LINQPad Screenshot]

[This help topic](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000151000000) explains why this is happening, which I think I understand, but would like to know what options there are for working around this behavior, especially in the context of making LINQPad (even) more powerful.

Interestingly, Visual Studio's debugger is able to display the properties of these objects, and even values for value types:

[image: Visual Studio debugging ArcObjects]

What mechanism does Visual Studio use to achieve this introspection, and why doesn't LINQPad's Dump method do the same? **Edit:** See related question about how VS does this: [How does Visual Studio's debugger/interactive window dump the properties of COM Objects in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14798159/386205)

The [ArcObjects .NET SDK](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/ao_home.html) includes PIAs with RCWs for each CoClass a COM interface may be implemented by, so I'm thinking it should be possible to wrap these objects programmatically.

As a workaround I have successfully used [`Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.createwrapperoftype.aspx) within my LINQ queries to coerce LINQPad to dump the properties of the object when I happen to know which CoClass should be used. Of course, this only properly dumps value type properties -- any COM-based reference type properties are still reported as `System.__ComObject`, so a proper solution would have to work recursively to get those wrapped as well.

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3348554/386205) I learned that the CoClass can be determined at runtime if it implements [`IPersist`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688695%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which a good portion of ArcObjects do. Can I somehow use this technique, or another one, to automatically coerce a `System.__ComObject` to the appropriate RCW from the PIAs? And if so, how can I implement this in LINQPad, e.g. by providing an [`ICustomMemberProvider`](http://www.linqpad.net/faq.aspx#extensibility) implementation? Can this be made to be recursive, so that properties that are also COM objects be wrapped as well?

I am using LINQPad 4.x which targets .NET 4.0, but am also interested in supporting LINQPad 2.x (so solutions that work on both .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 would be preferred, but that's not a requirement).

**Update:** I've figured out the first part of my question which was how to wrap a `System.__ComObject` in its RCW using the CLSID returned by `IPersist.GetClassID`. See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14756823/386205) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14765248/386205) for the code I'm using.

I would still like to know how I can work this into LINQPad's Dump method.

Comment: I don't know how Visual Studio does this. If you can figure this out, I can make LINQPad do the same.

Comment: Thanks Joe, that would be really great if you could! I can only speculate, but from my limited understanding there are two basic ways it could be working 1) Reflecting on the Primary Interop Assemblies for supported interfaces and 2) Using [`IDispatch`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDispatch). Since none of the objects I'm working with implement `IDispatch` it has to be the former, at least for the normal part of the debug view. I believe in VS2010's "Dynamic" view it uses `IDispatch`. With my objects, though, Dynamic view only says "No further information on this object could be discovered".

Comment: In the [linked answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14765248/386205), I am actually going a step further than either of these approaches by explicitly wrapping the COM Objects in their appropriate Runtime Callable Wrapper, which produces the most detailed output (because it includes members from all implemented interfaces), but this relies on the objects implementing `IPersist`, which is definitely not universal. Could you suggest whether providing an `ICustomMemberProvider` for my RCW conversion approach is feasible?

Comment: Yes, if you implement ICustomMemberProvider you can make LINQPad display whatever you like. Although it would be better if I could make LINQPad work like VS automatically with all COM objects.

Comment: Agreed that would be best. I wonder though, how can I implement `ICustomMemberProvider` in a way that it works on all `System.__ComObject`s? Or is it only possible to to use on user-defined types?

Comment: You can't implement the interface for all System.__ComObjects. Only for specific types.

Comment: Ah, that's what I feared. Thanks.

Comment: I have asked a related question about how VS does this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14798159/386205

Answer (score 0):

I've been having some of the same issues (except I'm working with iTunes COM library).

In visual studio you don't realize it but each debug window is asking the COM library to create the type when you open it.  This is different than Dump() which is, well, not interactive.

The only solution I've found is if I know what type the list is to do a `OfType<>()` cast to that type.  This will iterate over the list and force COM to create the elements.

So in your example above you would say:

```
var layers = map.EnumerateLayers("etc")
      .Select(s => s.OfType<Layer>())
      .Dump();
```

NB - Your millage may vary, it turns out for the OP example this was needed.

```
var layers = map.EnumerateLayers()
      .OfType<IGeoFeatureLayer>()
      .Dump();
```

Depending on the COM you might have to take this to the next step and pull out the members from there (with com you have to ask to get the value) something like this:

```
var layers = map.EnumerateLayers("etc")
      .Select(x => x.OfType<Layer>())
      .Select(x => new { x.Depth, x.Dimention, }) // etc 
      .Dump();
```

Sure would be nice if there was a "magical" way to make this happen, but I don't believe there is because of the nature of COM.

Comment: This does not compile for me. `'ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILayer' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.OfType<TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable)' has some invalid arguments

Instance argument: cannot convert from 'ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.ILayer' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable'`

Comment: Also if I understand correctly, OfType doesn't cast, it just filters by type. Using Cast itself does not help because you cannot cast `System.__ComObject` to a class outside of its hierarchy, only an interface, and even then that still just results in `System.__ComObject` being Dumped.

Comment: Lastly, the "magical" way of getting LINQPad to Dump the object is to wrap it explicitly with the appropriate RCW using Marshal.CreateWrapperOfType(). My question is more about automating this process in a generic, LINQPad-friendly way as this library has thousands of types. The fact that a large portion of the library implements `IPersist` could be useful to this endeavor, which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: This syntax compiles and filters as expected, but still dumps `System.__ComObject`: `var layers = map.EnumerateLayers().OfType<IGeoFeatureLayer>().Dump();`

Comment: @blah238 - yes that is why I had the 2nd part where I talk about using select and new.

Comment: Yes that is pretty much where I started and the whole point of my question is to avoid having to do it that way.